# MYSQL Update H251*R119336 with R119336

Tags: jquery, mysql

I want to update field *mpn* with a part of field *model*.
All records in field *model* with the string ***R119336** have to copied to field *mpn*.

### Fields: model -> mpn

> Examples:
>
> H251*R119336 will be R119336
>
> HA3251*R905678 will be R905678

I do not know how to create a working SQL for this one. Hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is finding the value after the `*`, then use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(model, '*', -1)
```

As an update:

```
update t
    set mpn = substring_index(model, '*', -1);
```